# Regex is not work for [][][.*] in the rsyslog conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, regular-expression, rsyslog

I want to redirect the following messages into the log file:

```
"[example]:[foo][bar]: "
"[example]:[foo][hello]: "
"[example]:[foo][world]: "
"[example]:[foo][other]: "
"[example]:[foo][text]: "
```

The content in the `3rd field` is dynamic text which contains lowercase [a-z] only:

```
"[example]:[foo][.*]: "
```

It works if I create the rsyslog conf file with the "`contains`" keyword:

```
:msg, contains, "[example]:[foo]" -/var/log/example.log
```

But the following regex is not work at all, no any message is logged:

```
:msg, regex, "\[example\]\:\[foo\]\[.*\]\:\ " -/var/log/example.log
```

What's wrong in my regex?

How to write the correct regex for matching the above messages with including all required fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there are two stages in the processing of the filter command, and each one interprets backslash escapes. The result is that if you want to match a literal `[` then your regex pattern is `\[`, but you need to escape the backslash since you are providing the pattern as a string, so have to use `\\[`.

You don't need to escape `:`, `]`, nor space, so you can use

```
:msg, regex, "\\[example]:\\[foo]\\[.*]: " -/var/log/example.log
```